# Onrowselecting JQgrid

Tags: c#, jqgrid-asp.net

i have two table and 2 JQGrid, when i click the row on the first GRID
then if the id on the first table is the same with the id on the second table, it 
will display all the items on the second GRID

**table 1** 
idA name 
1 A 
2 B 
3 C

**table 2**
UserID idB 
1 3 
2 3
3 3
4 3

here is my code (for displaying items in grid2)

```
protected void JQGrid1_OnRowSelected(object sender, Trirand.Web.UI.WebControls.JQGridRowSelectEventArgs e)
{
    SqlCommand cmdSelect = new SqlCommand();
    cmdSelect.Connection = conn;
    cmdSelect.CommandText = "select * from table2 where idB= @idB";
    cmdSelect.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmdSelect.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idB", idB);
    SqlDataAdapter daloadGrid = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdSelect);
    DataTable dtloadgrid = new DataTable();
    daloadGrid.Fill(dtloadgrid);
    JQGrid2.DataSource = dtloadgrid;
    JQGrid2.DataBind();
}
```

**QUESTION** how can i display items on grid two when i click on the row on grid one

like this one http://www.trirand.net/examples/grid/selection/masterdetail/default.aspx

Comment: What is your question? Are you sure that you use [jqGrid](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jqgrid/info) and not some commertial product like [jqSuite for ASP.NET](http://www.trirand.net/download.aspx)? Probably you should use another tag (like [jqgrid-asp.net](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jqgrid-asp.net/info)) for your question?

Comment: how can i display items on grid two when i click on the row on grid one

Comment: I personally don't use and don't know jqSuite, so I can't help you in pure jqSuite question.